# Telegram Tdlib TdApi TdLight UpdateUser - how to get an employee's phone number after changing his privacy

Tags: java, telegram, tdlib

The project needs to check whether the transferred number matches the number specified in the telegram, for this we ask our users to change the privacy so that these numbers can be compared, but when the privacy changes, the phone number is not displayed through the `GetUser` method.

I know `UpdateUser` caches the data, but how do I update the privacy of an employee by their id to get their number.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.